# Where are MCE (machine check events) logged in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, kernel

```
% journalctl
...
Dec 14 22:37:30 ray-desktop kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
-- Reboot --
Dec 14 22:40:08 ray-desktop kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x8e, date = 2018-03-24
...
```

/var/log/kern.log has:

```
...
Dec 14 22:37:30 ray-desktop kernel: [539775.847567] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Dec 14 22:40:09 ray-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x8e, date = 2018-03-24
Dec 14 22:40:09 ray-desktop kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-42-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-42.45-generic 4.15.18)
...
```

But Ubuntu 18.04 has no `mcelog` command or `/var/log/mcelog` file.

So *where* are the events logged?

Or more generally, how do I determine what hardware failed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mcelog` was removed in Debian 10+ (Buster) and [Ubuntu 18.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mcelog/+bug/1752251)+

The functionality has been replaced by `rasdaemon`.